# Is it possible to record private comments in LR5?

Tags: lightroom, metadata

Is there any way or place to add comments to photos in LR5. Not for clients to see but just additional info to remind me as to how the shot was taken? Such as "low sun over left shoulder"?

Comment: There comments in LR which seems obvious, so I am wondering if you mean comments which are not exported?

Comment: Yes comments that are not exported. Just for my personal reference. Thanks.

Comment: You can remove the comments as you export. That would seem to solve your problem (keep your comments, but not have the clients see them).

Comment: It's a bit of a hack/workaround, but perhaps using the Comments box under the Video category? I've not tested it (and can't right now) but in theory it shouldn't ever display in another app since it's irrelevant to pictures. 

Also, can I ask why you don't want a client seeing something as innocuous as you mention? I'd understand if it was something like "Client is a pain in the ass"...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Metadata Wrangler](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/metadata-wrangler) plugin from Jeffrey Friedl, in which you can strip some of the metadata at export time.

According to [this thread](http://www.lightroomforums.net/showthread.php?8765-Removing-keywords-on-export&s=9ad9ea5671187358947ef7b32350b975) you can also use the *Minimize embedded data* option at export time to remove keywords.

Comment: Could you summarize what's in that thread - in the event of a dead link we won't be able to read it, and would prefer answers here to be as self-contained as possible

Comment: There's actually not much in the thread, the question was roughly the same as the OP's question. As i said this function will strip keywords upon export, which could achieve what the OP asked.